# htaccess for rewriterule is not working with both rules

Tags: .htaccess

I want to make a redirection

From https://site.example/news-events/news/xyz to https://site.example/news/2023/xyz

xyz is a dynamic. It could be anything.

So I use this in my htaccess

```
redirectMatch 301 ^/news-events/news/(.*)$   /news/2023/$1
```

But in my htaccess I also have this rule

```
redirectMatch 301 ^/news-events/news/archive/2021-news-releases/?$ /news/2021
```

When I have both of these rules, my redirection `redirectMatch 301 ^/news-events/news/(.*)$   /news/2023/$1` is no longer working.

I am not sure what is wrong.

Comment: "When I have both of these rules, my redirection `redirectMatch 301 ^/news-events/news/(.*)$ /news/2023/$1` is no longer working" - That doesn't make sense, unless you mean the other (2nd rule) is not working? In which case you have the rules in the wrong order. So, what do you mean exactly by "not working"? Error? Incorrect redirect? Nothing? What URL are you requesting to test this? We would need to see your complete `.htaccess` file with these directives in place.

Answer (score 0):

With your shown samples and attempts please try following .htaccess rules file. Please make sure to clear your browser cache before testing your URLs.

```
RewriteEngine ON
##New redirect rule here..
RewriteRule ^news-events/(news)/([^/]*)/?$ /%1/2023/%2? [R=301,NC,L]

##Existing redirect rule from here..
RedirectMatch 301 ^/news-events/news/archive/2021-news-releases/?$ /news/2021  [NC,L]
```

Comment: @delphiman, could you please do let me know if these rules have worked for you?